# Trying to add collision but it traps my player in the top left corner?

Tags: python, pygame

Adding collision to the black tiles but it doesn't work and traps my character in the top left corner unable to move.

```
class platform():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.tile_list = []

        #load images
        rectangle_img = pygame.image.load('image/rect.png')

        row_count = 0
        for row in data:
            col_count = 0
            for tile in row:
                if tile == 1:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(rectangle_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                if tile == 2:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(rectangle_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                col_count += 1
            row_count +=1   
        def is_on(self, platform):
            return (pygame.Rect(rect.x, rect.y + dy+1, rect.width, rect.height)
                .colliderect(platform.rect))

    def draw(self):
        for tile in self.tile_list:
            window.blit(tile[0], tile[1])
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), tile[1], 2)`
```

I tried following other people's answers but I just can't understand collisions.

Answer (score 1):

### What are collisions anyway?

Collisions are when two shapes overlap with some area.

[image: Collision]

If you want to "resolve" collision (move elements in the way that they don't collide anymore), you need the information about the overlapping area.

### Resolving collisions

On the image it is clear how you want to move things apart:

[image: Resolving collision]

But in your case, you don't want to move platform (so, the platform is a static object), but player (dynamic/kinematic object).

[image: Moving red box]

### Moving and preserving energy

Let's re-imagine situation: player landing on the platform:

[image: Moving player]

With a blue arrow, I've marked the velocity of a player.
Imagine, the simplest way of resolving collisions:
Going back step by step in reverse of velocity:

[image: Collision and vector of solution]

How the next frame will look like?

[image: Frame after]

See? Now boxes don't collide anymore, but look, the same situation will happen over again, making player stuck to the wall.

So, what can be done? Resetting velocity of a player won't help either, as the player will be abruptly stuck to the wall and won't move to the left or right.

Assuming you don't have slopes, you can split velocity vector to the x and y axis and use method above, but separately for each of the axis:

[image: Fixing method above]
[image: Next frame]

### Code

I'm not going to write all code, but here is a simplification:

```
def move_player(player, box, max_tries):
    # Assume that the player is not touching box from the start
    if player.collide_if_moved(player.vel, box):  # Returns true if player collides if moved by vector, false otherwise.
        vel_x = player.vel.copy()
        vel_x.y = 0
        x_sign = 1 if vel_x.x > 0 else -1
        
        vel_y = player.vel.copy()
        vel_y.x = 0
        y_sign = 1 if vel_y.y > 0 else -1
        
        try_no = 0
        while player.collide_if_moved(vel_x, box):
            if try_no >= max_tried:
                # Break loop, if fails to resolve collision.
                return False  # Function unsuccessful
            vel_x.x -= x_sign
            try_no += 1
        
        
        try_no = 0
        while player.collide_if_moved(vel_y, box):
            if try_no >= max_tried:
                # Break loop, if fails to resolve collision.
                return False  # Function unsuccessful
            vel_y.y -= y_sign
            try_no += 1
        
        player.vel = vel_x + vel_y
    player.move()  # Moves player by the velocity
    return True  # Function successful
```

Please note that this implementation is not a physics-accurate simulation.
That is not a scope of this project. There are many more methods of implementing collision revolvers, this is just one of them.